# Taking last values from a list in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I had an asymmetric dataframe list like:

```
   1   2   3
0  a   b   c
1  d   e   NaN
2  f   NaN NaN
3  g   h   NaN
```

or a series like:

```
0 [a, b, c]
1 [d, e]
2 [f]
3 [g, h]
```

and I required the last value from each row to create another series like:

```
0  c
1  e
2  f
3  h
```

What would be the best way about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fillna` to propagate the last good value in each row and tale the last column, in the example provided

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:,2]

0    c
1    e
2    f
3    h
```

Comment: more generally: `.iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: I prefer your method :) +1

Comment: @ChrisA I was gonna say the same about yours lol. I think yours is more robust, but just for fun I did a time comparison and mine was roughly half the time. `518 µs < 1.02 ms`

Comment: oooft, rub it in :)

Comment: I try!...uh...also...my IDE could beat up your IDE!

Comment: @ChrisA, @G Thanks to both of you guys!

Comment: Note that in case of a row with all `np.nan` values, @G.Anderson's method returns, among others, the index of that row and a nan value, while @Chris A's method does consider that row in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html):

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).last()

0    c
1    e
2    f
3    h
dtype: object
```